# How to return String from Optional<String>?

Tags: javafx, dialog

I have the following function.

```
public String getSomething(){
   TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
   dialog.setHeaderText("X");
   dialog.setTitle("Y");
   Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
   return result;
}
```

Obviously, the returned value is not of `String` type. How could I return a `String` when result's type is `Optional<String>`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please accept the best answer if your problem has been solved. If not, please try to edit the question to improve it as much as possible.

Comment: I have to say, "Optional" is about the dumbest, most unnecessary thing added to Java .

Answer (score 14):

Try doing `result.get()` should return a string.

Comment: This invokes `toString` from `Optional` which usually isn't what you want. Lets say the dialog returns `"foo"`, then the returned string would be `"Optional[foo]"`.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that. Looked at documentation and edited it.

Comment: You should check `isPresent()` before because `get()` might throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like this to make sure you are protecting from null
`if(a. isPresent()) {a.get()}`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) which provides a default value in case the actual value is absent:

```java
public String getSomething(){
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
    dialog.setHeaderText("X");
    dialog.setTitle("Y");
    return dialog.showAndWait().orElse("n/a");
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, it is good to know about [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-)

Answer (score -1):

Use String.valueOf(optionalString);

```
Optional<String> s1 =Optional.of("Hello");
// s1 will print - Optional["Hello"]
String s1 = String.valueOf(optionalObj.get());
// now s1 will print "Hello"
```

this would extract the exact string literal from the optional object.

Comment: please be precise: as written, the snippet doesn't make sense .. Specifically: what is optionalObj? If it's of type Optional<String> the getter would already return a String, if it's another type, this is unrelated to question .. Plus: don't use get without checking if the value is available

Comment: optionalObj, is the optional object we are trying to get the string out from.

Comment: let your code speak :) And better not show a snippet that doesn't compile .. wondering: you are aware that you can edit your answer to improve it, aren't you?